# 401 HttpURLConnection error occurs randomly despite URL working on web (Android)

Tags: android, httprequest, httpurlconnection

After several successful http requests, a 401 error would occur out of the blues. It's very odd, because the GET URL works perfectly on the browser. Thus, I'm not sure why I'm receiving an authentication error on my android device. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Does this happen to every URL or one specific URL? On an Emulator on on an actual device?

Comment: @Fraggle Most times the GET URL works, but few times it just returns 401 error on android device (but it works when I paste into browser). This is on an actual device

Comment: @Fraggle I guess every URL is volatile, since they can all possibly send me 401 error at any moment